# 1 minute data: Japan, Australia and India stocks

Tags: market-data, historical-data, quote

Where I can find 1 minute historical market data for Japan, Australia and India stocks markets?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Thomson Reuters Tick History to get intraday data at 1 minute interval. However, you need to pay for that. Many university provide access to this database.